# How to position html elements when trying to animate with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a button for my website which is a `div` with a background image. I animated that button using jQuery, so that when the mouse hovers the button, it jumps 20px to the right and when the mouse leaves, it goes back to previous location.

Problem is, when I zoom in (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>scroll</kbd>), the whole animation becomes a mess. The button moves rapidly left to right, and of course not where it supposed to be.

I used `relative` position and pixel unit to position the elements.

How should I position things? `absolute` or `relative`? Pixel or percent?

Comment: I would use em units. Set the base font-size to 10px and refer to this using em and rem (root em) units. This will make everything scale accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [article](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) explain absolute and relative, How Do They Differ?. my practice I first `wrap` my `absolute` with `relative`

example:

html

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrap {
  float:left;
  position:relative
}
.content {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is use only CSS. It's neat and does the job well. Here's a demo

http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/GyVTZ/

```
img {
    margin-top:20px;
}
img:hover {
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: with css the button jumps around
i want it to move smoothly
and there are some other animations like sliding 
i need to use jquery